# sass --watch : could not find option named "watch"

Tags: npm, sass

Simple one, but could not find the answer anywhere online! Installed sass globally (`npm install -g sass`) on my Mac.

This works as expected:

```
sass style.scss style.css
```

Then I try:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

And get:

```
Could not find an option named "watch".

Usage: sass <input> [output]

    --[no-]stdin          Read the stylesheet from stdin.
    --[no-]indented       Use the indented syntax for input from stdin.
-I, --load-path=<PATH>    A path to use when resolving imports.
                      May be passed multiple times.

-s, --style=<NAME>        Output style.
                      [expanded (default), compressed]

-c, --[no-]color          Whether to emit terminal colors.
-q, --[no-]quiet          Don't print warnings.
--[no-]trace          Print full Dart stack traces for exceptions.
-h, --help                Print this usage information.
    --version             Print the version of Dart Sass.
```

What am I missing??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I gave up on `sass` as tried above, and went for a solution with `webpack`.

Another option I tried which worked was to use `node-sass`.

Comment: For those wondering why it doesn't work, the `sass` package (a.k.a `Dart Sass`) doesn't support the `--watch` argument yet at the time of writing this according to [this issue](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/264) on their repo.

Answer (score 1):

First create the SASS's folder, and in there create your SASS's file. Example:

```
sass/styles.sass
```

In your project root folder, open the console and type the command:

```
sass --watch sass/styles.sass:css/styles.css
```

This command will create your CSS's folder and CSS's file. In addition to compiling your .sass content for your `.css`.

Answer (score -1):

```
I solved running this command on your terminal
```

echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

i hope that help

Comment: that didn't really help... I got another error: `sysctl: illegal option -- p`